# How to pad decimal places using seq

Tags: linux, bash

I can't figure out how to use seq to pad decimal places.  Here is what I tried based on what i found online...

```
for U in $(seq -f "%0.2g" 0 0.1 1)
```

but it fails to work.

I am looking to get the output,

```
0.00
0.10
0.20
...
```

Comment: `"%0.2f"` maybe? And you skipped the `; do echo $U; done`, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`g` in the [file format notation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap05.html#tag_05) removes trailing zeros. You want `f`:

```
seq -f "%0.2f" 0 0.1 1
```

resulting in

```
0.00
0.10
0.20
0.30
0.40
0.50
0.60
0.70
0.80
0.90
1.00
```

The relevant excerpts from the spec are these:

> `f`,`F`
>
> The floating-point number argument shall be written in decimal notation in the style [-]*ddd*.*ddd*, where the number of digits after the radix character (shown here as a decimal point) shall be equal to the *precision* specification.
>
> `e`,`E`
>
> The floating-point number argument shall be written in the style [-]*d*.*ddd*e±*dd* (the symbol '±' indicates either a <plus-sign> or minus-sign), where there is one digit before the radix character (shown here as a decimal point) and the number of digits after it is equal to the precision.
>
> `g`,`G`
>
> The floating-point number argument shall be written in style `f` or `e` (or in style `F` or `E` in the case of a `G` conversion specifier), with the precision specifying the number of significant digits. [...] **Trailing zeros are removed from the result.**